# What we add under dev_dependencies in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a silly question regarding dev_dependencies in flutter, I am planning to use `mock_cloud_firestore` and in its installation page it says that we need to add it in the `dependencies` section of pubspec.yaml

I think `mock_cloud_firestore` is not a production dependency but a dev dependency if so why we need to add it under dependencies?

Also what we add under `dev_dependencies`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is mentioned in [Dart's official docs](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies#dev-dependencies):

> Pub supports two flavors of dependencies: regular dependencies and dev dependencies. Dev dependencies differ from regular dependencies in that dev dependencies of packages you depend on are ignored

Therefore, I believe it safer to put it under dependencies during development and remove it from pubspec when personal testing is finished. But below quote from the official doc is more clear:

> The rule for deciding between a regular or dev dependency is simple: If the dependency is imported from something in your lib or bin directories, it needs to be a regular dependency. If it’s only imported from test, example, etc. it can and should be a dev dependency.

Answer (score 8):

you can run below command `flutter pub add <packagename> --dev` to add under dev dependencies

and you can run below command `flutter pub add <packagename>` to add normal dependencies.

Both make an entry within the pubspec.yaml file under different headers.

dev_dependencies only have packages and tools which help the development process for the developer and are not really needed in production . eg. code generation etc